# Error on nuget restore step in azure devops build after upgrade to .net 5

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild, nuget

I have a build pipeline in azure devops that worked fine for net core 3.1, then I upgraded this project to .net 5.0 and the build doesn't work anymore, it stops on the nuget restore step

[image]

this is the error log

```
 MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.200.19.31001' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\bin'. Use option -MSBuildVersion to force nuget to use a specific version of MSBuild.
MSBuild P2P timeout [ms]: 120000
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Preview\MSBuild\Current\bin\msbuild.exe "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\xbcsorbg.z0f.nugetinputs.targets" /t:GenerateRestoreGraphFile /nologo /nr:false /v:q /p:NuGetRestoreTargets="C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\p0q3isxq.jbq.nugetrestore.targets" /p:RestoreUseCustomAfterTargets="True" /p:RestoreTaskAssemblyFile="C:\agent\_work\_tool\NuGet\5.7.0\x64\nuget.exe" /p:RestoreSolutionDirectory="C:\agent\_work\12\s\Framework\\" /p:RestoreConfigFile="C:\agent\_work\12\Nuget\tempNuGet_1947.config" /p:SolutionDir="C:\agent\_work\12\s\Framework\\" /p:SolutionName="Tenper Core"
NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException: Exception of type 'NuGet.CommandLine.ExitCodeException' was thrown.
   at NuGet.CommandLine.MsBuildUtility.<GetProjectReferencesAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<GetDependencyGraphSpecAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.RestoreCommand.<DetermineInputsFromMSBuildAsync>d__63.MoveNext()
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(54,5): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')". Method '[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)). Check that all parameters are defined, are of the correct type, and are specified in the right order. [C:\agent\_work\12\s\Framework\Interfaces\Interfaces.csproj]
C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(54,5): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')". Method '[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier' not found. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)). Check that all parameters are defined, are of the correct type, and are specified in the right order. [C:\agent\_work\12\s\Framework\DI\DI.csproj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Use .net core task`+`Dotnet core task` with restore command.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10'
    includePreviewVersions: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

It's **strongly recommended** to use `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` tasks for projects that target `.net core`. See [this statement from Nuget task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops):

If you are working with `.NET Core` or `.NET Standard`, use the [.NET Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops), which has full support for all package scenarios and it's currently supported by dotnet.

Also, you should use `5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10` in `UseDotNet@2` task according to the error message.

Answer (score 1):

The issue arises because the agent you are not using .Net Core sdk 5.0 preview 8.

According to your error log, you are using `SDK 5.0.100-rc.1` which is not supported `[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')`.

**How to solve this issue:**

You can replace your original .Net Core download tasks with the following download task:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.0.100-preview.8.20417.9'
    includePreviewVersions: true
```

Then rebuild your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the help. now I got the error error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found. on the same step

Comment: @Luiz Bicalho Please try manually setting the environment variable `MSBuildSDKsPath` to `C:\agent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.8.20417.9\Sdks`.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue. I upgraded my project from 3.1 -> 5.0, and the restore option failed. However, I was using the dotnet cli to restore the nuget packages.

Turns out, there was some project called `WorkerExtensions.csproj` that was being restored, and was built using 3.1. I'm not sure where this project was referenced at all, as it isn't anywhere in the project I was building.

```
  Project.AzureFunction -> /home/vsts/work/1/s/publish_output/Project.AzureFunction.dll
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /tmp/o0lv1ony.pel/WorkerExtensions.csproj (in 6.89 sec).
  WorkerExtensions -> /tmp/o0lv1ony.pel/buildout/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.dll
##[error]/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): Error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.8 at [/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

The only thing I found close was the `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http` nuget. After investigation, I still can't figure it out.

Regardless, to get the build working and to deploy it, I included both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 in the YAML as following. I'm hoping to properly address the issue in the future.

```yaml
# For some reason, Azure Functions still require .NET Core 3.x even with .NET 5. Maybe it won't be needed in the future.
    - task: UseDotNet@2 
      displayName: "Install .NET Core 3.x"
      inputs:
        version: '3.x'
        packageType: sdk

    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Install .NET 5.x'
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: '5.x'
```